# Token vue js, jwt

Tags: vue.js, jwt, token

I want to ask, how do I use the token in localstorage to be a token that can be used in all features.
[This token from localstorage](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TIbVd.png)
[And this token from auth before](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Rdi3N.png).
and i want use token from localstorage to access all features alias token localstorage to be a token global.
this is my login form code:

```
async handleSubmit () {
      // const self = this
      console.log('on handleSubmit()')
      this.$refs.loginForm.validate(async (valid) => {
        if (this.loginLoading) return
        this.loginLoading = true
        try {
          if (valid) {
            const { userName, password } = this.form
            const res1 = await this.handleLogin({ userName, password })
            const res2 = await this.getUserInfo()
            console.log('>>> handleSubmit:33', { res1, res2 })
            console.log('>>> confighomename', this.$config.homeName)
            const tokenstring = JSON.stringify(res1.access_token)
            localStorage.setItem('token', tokenstring)

            this.$emit('on-login-success', {
              username: this.form.userName,
              password: this.form.password
            })
```

This handlelogin code :

```
async handleLogin ({ commit }, { userName, password }) {
      try {
        userName = userName.trim()

        const res = await RestClient.request({
          url: '/api/auth/login', method: 'POST', data: { username: userName, password }
        })

        const data = res.data

        commit('setTagNavList', [])
        commit('setToken', data.id)
        commit('setData', data)

        return data
      } catch (error) {
        console.error('>>> Error in handleLogin API: ', error)
        throw error
      }
```

so where i can use token from localstorage to every features ?

token from localstorage replace authorization and can be use in every place

Answer (score 0):

To use a JWT token stored in localStorage as a global token in a Vue.js application, first you should store the token somewhere (localStorage or cookie), then attach it to your requests via interceptors.
So, typically after login you should:

```
localStorage.setItem('token', JSON.stringify(res1.access_token));
```

then (assuming using Axios):

```
function getToken() {
  return JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('token'));
}
axios.interceptors.request.use(config => {
  const token = getToken();
  if (token) {
    config.headers.Authorization = `Bearer ${token}`;
  }
  return config;
});
```

Mostly your token persists in your localstorage, and you handle the appropriate logic inside your interceptor.

Comment: where i use that code ? in my handlesubmit ?